# Output of hidden layer for every epoch and storing that in a list in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, activation-function

I have a keras MLP with single hidden layer. I am using a multilayer perceptron with some specific number of nodes in a single hidden layer. I want to extract the activation value for all the neurons of that hidden layer when a batch is passed and I want to do that for every epoch and store that in a list to explore. My representation is like following.

```
class myNetwork:
# Architecture of our neural network.
def multilayerPerceptron(self, Num_Nodes_hidden,input_features,output_dims,activation_function = 'relu', learning_rate=0.001,
                        momentum_val=0.00):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(Num_Nodes_hidden, input_dim =input_features, activation=activation_function))
    model.add(Dense(output_dims,activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy",
                  optimizer=SGD(lr = learning_rate, momentum = momentum_val),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

Below is my call for another part where I am using lambdacallbacks to save the weights. I want something similar but this time to save the actual activation values for the hidden layer.

```
from keras.callbacks import LambdaCallback
import pickle
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.callbacks import CSVLogger



# setting_parameters and calling inputs.
val = myNetwork()
vals = val.multilayerPerceptron(8,4,3,'relu',0.01)
batch_size_val = 20
number_iters = 200
weights_ih = []
weights_ho = []
activation_vals = []


get_activtaion = LambdaCallback(on_epoch_end=lambda batch, logs: activation_vals.append("What should I put Here"))




print_weights = LambdaCallback(on_epoch_end=lambda batch, logs: weights_ih.append(vals.layers[0].get_weights()))
print_weights_1 = LambdaCallback(on_epoch_end=lambda batch, logs: weights_ho.append(vals.layers[1].get_weights()))



history_callback = vals.fit(X_train, Y_train,
                                 batch_size=batch_size_val,
                                 epochs=number_iters,
                                 verbose=0,
                                 validation_data=(X_test, Y_test),
                                 callbacks = [csv_logger,print_weights,print_weights_1,get_activtaion])
```

I am super confused and I am not sure what I should put in GetActivtion. Please let me know what I should there in order to get the activation value for all the samples of the batch for that iteration value of the weights.

Answer (score 4):

**weights_callback to get weights of each layer:**

```
weights_list = [] #[epoch][layer][unit(l-1)][unit(l)]

def save_weights(model):
    inner_list = []
    for layer in model.layers:
        inner_list.append(layer.get_weights()[0])
    weights_list.append(inner_list)

weights_callback = LambdaCallback(on_epoch_end = lambda batch, logs:save_weights(model))
```

**activations_callback to get output of each layer:**

```
activations_list = [] #[epoch][layer][0][X][unit]

def save_activations(model):
    outputs = [layer.output for layer in model.layers]
    functors = [K.function([model.input],[out]) for out in outputs]
    layer_activations = [f([X_input_vectors]) for f in functors]
    activations_list.append(layer_activations)

activations_callback = LambdaCallback(on_epoch_end = lambda batch, logs:save_activations(model))
```

**apply callbacks:**

```
result = model.fit(... , callbacks = [weights_callback, activations_callback], ...)
```

**Refs:**

- [Keras: Interpreting the output of get_weights()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46817085/keras-interpreting-the-output-of-get-weights)
- [Keras, How to get the output of each layer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41711190/keras-how-to-get-the-output-of-each-layer)

Comment: Why use ```lambda batch``` in ```on_epoch_end```?

Comment: For maintaining the callback signature mentioned by OP. It can be passed as a parameter if needed.

Comment: I mean it's more proper to have ``` lambda epoch``` in ```on_epoch_end```, in case it will be used for per-epoch computations